# Keeping gradients while rearranging data in a tensor, with pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a scheme where I store a matrix with zeros on the diagonals as a vector. I want to later on optimize over that vector, so I require gradient tracking.
My challenge is to reshape between the two.

I want - for domain specific reasons - keep the order of data in the matrix so that transposed elements of the `W` matrix next to each other in the vector form.

The size of the `W` matrix is subject to change, so I start with enumering items in the top-left part of the matrix, and continue outwards.

I have come up with two ways to do this. See code snippet.

```
import torch
import torch.sparse

w = torch.tensor([10,11,12,13,14,15],requires_grad=True,dtype=torch.float)
i = torch.LongTensor([
    [0, 1,0],
    [1, 0,1], 
    [0, 2,2],
    [2, 0,3],
    [1, 2,4],
    [2, 1,5],
])
v = torch.FloatTensor([1,      1,      1 ,1,1,1   ])
reshaper = torch.sparse.FloatTensor(i.t(), v, torch.Size([3,3,6])).to_dense()
W_mat_with_reshaper = reshaper @ w
W_mat_directly = torch.tensor([
  [0,    w[0],  w[2],],
  [w[1],    0,  w[4],],
  [w[3], w[5],     0,],
])
print(W_mat_with_reshaper)
print(W_mat_directly)
```

and this gives output

```
tensor([[ 0., 10., 12.],
        [11.,  0., 14.],
        [13., 15.,  0.]], grad_fn=<UnsafeViewBackward>)
tensor([[ 0., 10., 12.],
        [11.,  0., 14.],
        [13., 15.,  0.]])
```

As you can see, the direct way to reshape the vector into a matrix does not have a grad function, but the multiply-with-a-reshaper-tensor does. Creating the reshaper-tensor seems like it will be a hassle, but on the other hand, manually writing the matrix for is also infeasible.

Is there a way to do arbitrary reshapes in pytorch that keeps grack of gradients?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of constructing `W_mat_directly` from the *elements* of `w`, try assigning `w` into `W`:

```py
W_mat_directly = torch.zeros((3, 3), dtype=w.dtype)
W_mat_directly[(0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2), (1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1)] = w
```

You'll get

> ```
> tensor([[ 0., 10., 11.],
>         [12.,  0., 13.],
>         [14., 15.,  0.]], grad_fn=<IndexPutBackward>)
> ```

Comment: This is useful thanks, but what if you have to assign the values of w a few times in the w_mat_directly or if you didn't need all the elements of w. Would this still work if you had multiple assignments using slices of w? What if you needed elements like w[0]*w[1]+w[3]^5?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the facts that:

- slicing preserves gradients while indexing doesn't;
- concatenation preserves gradients while tensor creation doesn't.

```py
tensor0 = torch.zeros(1)
W_mat_directly = torch.concatenate(
    [tensor0, w[0:1], w[1:2], w[1:2], tensor0, w[4:5], w[3:4], w[5:6], tensor0]
).reshape(3,3)
```

With this approach you can apply arbitrary functions to the elements of the initial tensor `w`.